# Solr: How to use elevation component, Fuzzy Search and Boosting togather?

Tags: boost, solr

When i use solr elevation component without boosting and fuzzy search it works perfectly. Elevated documents come at the top than the other matched documents based on score

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/collection1/elevate?q=ipod&wt=json&indent=true
```

But when i use elevation component with boosting and fuzzy search the high score documents come at the top not the elevated one why? I still want elevated document to come at top.

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/collection1/elevate?q=(black ipod~)^5 ("black ipod")^10&wt=json&indent=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Elevate component doesn't work with fuzzy string.

`q` should match exactly what you entered in elevate.xml file

```
<query text="ipod">
   <doc id="MA147LL/A" />  <!-- put the actual ipod at the top -->
   <doc id="IW-02" exclude="true" /> <!-- exclude this cable -->
 </query>
```